# Creating Apps In Google Web Toolkit, Hosting Options?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

So i have been looking into GWT and it does look pretty interesting as i do have experience in programming in java and being able to create webapps does look very interesting to me.

I have looked at some of the basic tutorials and have got GWT working in my eclipse environment. Now, If i was to begin creating webapps with it how would i go about uploading and hosting my app. I have only used PHP and MySQL for web development so i would always just use Apache, I am not to sure about GWT hosting. Does it require the app to be hosted on googles App Engine platform or can I setup a server like to usually do when using Apache?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Using GWT does not require you to host your app on App Engine. You can host a GWT app on any host.

If you want your server to be written in Java, to take advantage of some of the more useful features of GWT, you will obviously need to find a host that allows you to run Java. But you can write a GWT app that communicates with a PHP server, or a Python server, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with PHP + MySQL it's not a bad idea to stick to that and just add your compiled GWT output as another component that you upload. Switching to App Engine requires a fundamental change in the way you write and design your application which means you'll be learning new front-end and back-end technologies at the same time. Just as an example, a simple full-text search on one field is pretty trivial for a small php + mysql app but because App Engine forces you to write extremely scalable code it's not trivial on GAE.